# Populate multiple fields using lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb and wanted to populate two ids using lookup

Eg:

```
{
      "sampleId1": "5kjksds8nkjfhsjfi8kl",
      "sampleId2": "7jhjshfi9jsfkjsdfkkk"
    }
```

I am using aggregate framework to query the data and wanted to popualte both ids.

I want `$loopup` to populate both ids which is similar to

```
Model.find().populate('sampleId1').populate('sampleId2')
```

Comment: What do both your documents look like that you want to do a `$lookup` on?
 Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: are you using mongoose ?

Comment: @ManjeetThakur yes. I am using mongoose

Answer (score 2):

For your case, I want to suggest you [mongoose-autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) like this

```
    const autopopulate = require('mongoose-autopopulate')'

    const sampleSchema = new Schema({
      sampleId1: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ColleactionName', autopopulate: {select: 'firstName, lastName'}},
    sampleId2: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ColleactionName', autopopulate: {select: 'firstName, lastName'}}
    })


    sampleSchema.plugin(autopopulate)

module.exports = mongoose.model('sampleSchema', sampleSchema)
```

> now whenever you request for find it automatically populates all field
>   who have `Schema.ObjectId`

```
let criteria = {},
projection = {},
options = {lean: true}


Model.find(criteria, projection, options, (err, result) => {
 console.log(result); // See out-put 
})
```

The second thing you need to check in your schema that sampleId1 and sampleId2 both have type `type: Schema.ObjectId` with reference  of collection name `ref: 'ColleactionName'`

> the second way to this thing which you already have done you question

```
sampleSchema.
  find(...).
  populate('sampleId1').
  populate('sampleId2').
  exec();
```

Comment: Tried the autopopulate plugin however it doesn't seem to work when using aggregation query.

Comment: Works well, only except populate only two fields. I replaced comma with space, so I could populate 3 or more fields. Thanks for your help.                      
... ... ...sampleId1: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ColleactionName', autopopulate: {select: 'firstName lastName birthday'}},... ... ...